отличия между Debug.Log и print в unity
Чем отличаются Debug.Log и print в Unity и есть ли у них различия?

Это одно и тоже. Разница только в том, что print() является методом  MonoBehaviour, который в свою очередь вызывает Debug.Log().

print() Description:
Logs message to the Unity Console (identical to Debug.Log).

спасибо большое!

Такое происходит, когда делают новый функционал, но старый оставляют, что бы уже написанный код не выдавал ошибок. Debug это статический класс, который можно использовать где угодно, а print() говно мамонта, которое есть только в MonoBehaviour.
